Trouble manipulating the poisson distribution
I am having trouble understanding my lecture notes on the Poisson Distribution. I transcribed them below:

Fundamental properties: $$ P(N(t+h) - N(t) = 1) = λh + o(h) $$ $$
> P(N(t+h) - N(t) > 1) = o(h) $$ $$ P(N(t+h) - N(t) = 0) = 1 - λh + o(h)
> $$
Where $o(h)$ represents terms that approach zero faster than $h$ as $h
> \to 0$.
Probability of exactly k events in (t, t+h):
Let $P_k(t)$ be the probability of k events in time t. We can write:
$$ P_k(t+h) = P_k(t)(1-λh) + P_{k-1}(t)λh + o(h) $$
Rearranging:
$$ \frac{P_k(t+h) - P_k(t)}{h} = -λP_k(t) + λP_{k-1}(t) +
> \frac{o(h)}{h} $$
As $h \to 0$, this becomes a differential equation:
$$ \frac{dP_k(t)}{dt} = -λP_k(t) + λP_{k-1}(t) $$
For k = 0: $$ \frac{dP_0(t)}{dt} = -λP_0(t) $$
Solving this: $$ P_0(t) = e^{-λt} $$
For k > 0, we can solve recursively:
$$ P_k(t) = \frac{(λt)^k e^{-λt}}{k!} $$


Question 1: I don't understand the limit was evaluated in "Fundamental Properties". I tried to do this myself and got 0:
$$
   f(0, \lambda) = 0 \cdot \lambda \cdot e^{-0 \cdot \lambda} = 0
   $$
$$
   \lim_{h \to 0} f(h, \lambda) = \lim_{h \to 0} h \lambda e^{-h \lambda}
   $$
$$
   \lim_{h \to 0} h \lambda e^{-h \lambda} = \lambda \cdot \lim_{h \to 0} h \cdot e^{-h \lambda}
   $$
$$
   \lim_{h \to 0} h \cdot e^{-h \lambda} = \lim_{h \to 0} h \cdot 1 = 0
   $$

Question 2: I don't understand how the recursive equation was solved. I understand the first differential equation and its solution - but when I tried to solve the recursive relation for a specific case (e.g. 3 events), I end up with another differential equation to which I don't know the solution.


Can someone assist me here please?
